# iperf connection failed

Tags: iperf

I am very new to networking, and slightly more familiar with Ubuntu CLI. I am trying to test speeds across my home LAN from a laptop connected via ethernet, to a server connected ethernet. They both have the same version of iperf, and the server displays the expected message of "Server listening on TCP port ..."

When I try and invoke

```
iperf -c 192.168.1.xxx
```

on the laptop, it gives me an error of "connection failed: connection timed out".

Where do I start for debugging?!

Comment: Read `man iperf`. Can you `ping` each other?